# Could not get Device Token for Device running iOS 8+ (APNS)

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, token

I am developing an iOS application with deployment target of iOS 8. Somehow I am **not getting** the **delegate callbacks** for both **application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken** and **application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError**. 
While running in simulator, the application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError is called (**which is expected**) but when on device neither one of the methods are called.

Code written in application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions for registering for APNS:

```
let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
let notificationSetting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSetting) 
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Regarding the **certificates**, both my Production and Development certificates seems fine. Followed the same steps to create as mentioned in Member Center and the **APP ID** also shows **Green Dots** along the **Push Notification** field for both Dev and Distribution. Also the Production certificate created seems valid.

I have recreated the certificates, checked the BundleId, removed the older certificates from KeyChain replaced them with new Certificates. 
Also, removed the existing provisioning profiles on the device (using xCode) just to ensure that the previous profiles on the devices are interfering. But **no success**.

Can't really figure out what could be the issue. However I was able to manage to successfully send the remote notification to device a couple of times.

Comment: I have same issue today. If you check apsd logs, there is a SSL error. But on my case it works on iOS8.

Comment: I'm having the same issue today, too. Only development APN device token is failing; prod works fine. Our code isn't getting the failure callback invoked, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apns sandbox seems down today. It responds with code 200 to push notifications, but doesn't deliver the push notification to the device.

Note that https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ doesn't show anything anormal, probably because sandbox monitoring isn't very high on their priority.

Comment: totally... had the exact same experience

Comment: Yep, seems working fine now. Didn't know about the system-page, will be checking that page first (bookmarked it as soon as i opened) and that page showed the exact time when there were issues with development services.